# How to get some text values in python below text format

Tags: python

I have sentences like

```
// string1 = value1
// string2 = value2.....
```

so on, how can I get only "values" using python

Comment: Actually I am thinking that need to take values in a list. is it right.

Answer (score 3):

```
print [line.split('=',1)[-1].strip() for line in s.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> strs="""
// string1 = value1
// string2 = value2
"""
>>> [x.split('=')[1].strip() for x in strs.split('\n') if x.strip()]
['value1', 'value2']
```